# Run some bash code in groovy file/Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I Writing a stage in jenkinsfile where I have to add some bash code, but its not compiling at the last line.

```
stage('Pre Build Stage') {

    def deploy_property_basename = "deploy"
    sh """
    mkdir $WORKSPACE/resp
    cd $WORKSPACE
    git clone -b master ${env.GIT_REPO} build     
    cd $WORKSPACE/build
    cp pom.xml ..
    artifactId=$(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:artifactId/text()' | xmllint --shell ./pom.xml | grep -v /)
    """
}
```

any idea how I can get past this, the error seems to be the way I am assigning the echo output to artifactId.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the "steps" declaration try

```
stage('Pre Build Stage') {

def deploy_property_basename = "deploy"
steps{
sh """
   mkdir $WORKSPACE/resp
   cd $WORKSPACE
   git clone -b master ${env.GIT_REPO} build     
   cd $WORKSPACE/build
   cp pom.xml ..
   artifactId=$(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat    /x:project/x:artifactId/text()' | xmllint --shell ./pom.xml | grep -v /) """
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.